# Using NLTK, how to search for concepts in a text

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, nltk

I'm novice to both Python and NLTK. So, I'm trying to see the representation of some concepts in text using NLTK. I have a CSV file which looks like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8hPg.png)

And I want to see how frequent, e.g., Freedom, Courage, and all other concepts are. I also want to know how to make sure the code looks for bi and trigrams. However, the code I have below only allows me to look for a **single** list of words in a text (Preps.txt [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQJe.png) ).

The output I expect is something like:
Concept = Frequency in text, i.e., Freedom = 10, Courage = 20

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus_root = '/Users/Muhsa/Myfolder/Concepts' #this is where the texts I want to study are located
Concepts= PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
Concepts.fileids()
for fileid in Concepts.fileids():
    text3 = Concepts.words(fileid)
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import FreqDist
text3 = Concepts.words(fileid)
preps = open('preps.txt', encoding="utf-8")
rawpreps = preps.read() #preps refer to the file that has the list of words
tokens = word_tokenize(rawpreps)
texty = nltk.Text(tokens)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in text3)
for m in texty:
    print(m + ':', fdist[m], end=' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without having your data in a usable format. Also, it is important to see the code you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: Hi, how about now?

Comment: What does `preps.txt` look like ? What would your desired output look like ?

Comment: I added a screenshoot of preps in the original post. The output I expect is something like: 
Concept = Frequency in text, i.e., Freedom = 10, Courage = 20, which I should be able to export to a CSV file. @ygorg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganised your code a little bit. I assumed you had 1 file per concept words, and that 'preps.txt' only contained the courage words but not the others.

I hope it is easy to understand.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import FreqDist

# Load the courage vocabulary
with open('preps.txt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    content = file.read() #preps refer to the file that has the list of words
    courage_words = content.split('\n')  # This is a list of words
# load freedom and development words in the same fashion

# Load the corpus
corpus_root = '/Users/Muhsa/Myfolder/Concepts' #this is where the texts I want to study are located
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')

# Count the number of word in the whole corpus that are also in the courage vocabulry
courage_freq = len([w for w in corpus.words() if w in courage_words])
print('Corpus contains {} courage words'.format(courage_freq))

# For each file in the corpus
for file_id in corpus.fileids():
    # Count the number of word in the file that are also in courage word
    file_freq = len([w for w in corpus.words(file_id) if w in courage_words])
    print(file_id, file_freq)
```

Or better

```py
# Load concept vocabulary in different files, in a python dictionary
concept_voc = {}
for file_path in ['courage.txt', 'freedom.txt', 'development.txt']:
    concept_name = file_path.replace('.txt', '')
    with open(file_path) as f:
        voc = f.read().split('\n')
        concept_voc[concept_name] = voc

# Load concept vocabulary in a csv file, each column is one vocabulary, the first line is the "name" 
df = pd.read_csv('to_dict.csv')
convept_voc = df.to_dict('columns')

# concept_voc['courage'] returns the list of courage words


# And then for each concept compute the frequency as before
for concept in concept_voc:
    voc = concept_voc[concept]
    corpus_freq = len([w for w in corpus.words() if w in voc])
    print(concept, '=', corpus_freq)
```

Comment: Thank you, @ygorg ! The code is so useful in case I'd like to make each concept in a separate file. But I was thinking instead of having like a 1000 files for a 1000 concepts, I could add all concepts in one CSV file and use it. That was what I had in mind.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a way to load a csv file.